# Why does Automattic crawl my wordpress site constantly?

Tags: web-hosting

The IP is 103.115.8.95 and it has been scanning my site for many months, every day! Sometimes a dozen hits, sometimes 30 or 40 hits in one day. If I block the IPs using the most popular plugins it is ineffective.

Comment: I now see you already have a very old question https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45605/who-is-automattic-and-why-are-they-visiting-my-non-wordpress-site-so-often with answers that you have not accepted.  What more information do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Automattic is the name of the company that creates WordPress.

Do you use any plugins created by Automattic?  Jetpack, Akismet, Vaultpress and Crowdsignal are the ones I know of.  If so, that could be the source of traffic from Automattic.